# pythonic popup messagebox in dearpygui (asyncio or sync way)

Tags: python, messagebox, dearpygui

for person who is looking for pythonic popup messagebox in dearpygui, hope it can help

target:

```py
do_sth_step1(...)
user_response = msgbox('Confirm?')  # Yes/No
if user_response == 'Yes':
    do_sth_step2(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

and the solution found:

```py
import time
import inspect
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg
dpg.create_context()

dpg_callback_queue = []


def msgbox():

    def on_msgbox_btn_click(sender, data, user_data):
        nonlocal resp
        resp = dpg.get_item_label(sender)
        dpg.hide_item(popup)
        # dpg.delete_item(popup)

    with dpg.popup(parent=dpg.last_item(), modal=True) as popup:
        dpg.add_text('goto step 2?')
        with dpg.group(horizontal=True):
            dpg.add_button(label='Yes', callback=on_msgbox_btn_click)
            dpg.add_button(label='No', callback=on_msgbox_btn_click)
    dpg.show_item(popup)

    resp = None
    while not resp:
        # print('waiting for response ...')
        # time.sleep(0.01)  # NOT needed
        handle_callbacks_and_render_one_frame()  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    return resp


def on_btn_click(sender, data, user_data):
    print('do sth step 1 ...')
    resp = msgbox()
    if resp == 'Yes':
        print('do sth step 2 ...')
    print('done!')


def main():
    with dpg.window(tag='prim'):
        dpg.add_button(label='Submit', callback=on_btn_click)
    dpg.create_viewport(title='test msgbox', width=600, height=300)

    # start_dpg()
    dpg.setup_dearpygui()
    dpg.set_primary_window('prim', True)
    dpg.show_viewport()
    dpg.configure_app(manual_callback_management=True)
    while dpg.is_dearpygui_running():
        handle_callbacks_and_render_one_frame()
    dpg.destroy_context()


def run_callbacks():
    global dpg_callback_queue
    while dpg_callback_queue:
        job = dpg_callback_queue.pop(0)
        if job[0] is None:
            continue
        sig = inspect.signature(job[0])
        args = []
        for i in range(len(sig.parameters)):
            args.append(job[i+1])
        result = job[0](*args)


def handle_callbacks_and_render_one_frame():
    global dpg_callback_queue
    dpg_callback_queue += dpg.get_callback_queue() or []  # retrieves and clears queue
    # print(f'jobs: {jobs}')
    run_callbacks()
    dpg.render_dearpygui_frame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and asyncio way:

```py
import asyncio
import inspect
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

dpg.create_context()


async def msgbox():

    def on_msgbox_btn_click(sender, data, user_data):
        # print('clicked msgbox button')
        nonlocal resp
        resp = dpg.get_item_label(sender)
        dpg.hide_item(popup)
        # dpg.delete_item(popup)
        ev.set()

    with dpg.popup(parent=dpg.last_item(), modal=True) as popup:
        dpg.add_text('goto step 2?')
        with dpg.group(horizontal=True):
            dpg.add_button(label='Yes', callback=on_msgbox_btn_click)
            dpg.add_button(label='No', callback=on_msgbox_btn_click)
    dpg.show_item(popup)

    resp = None
    # while not resp:  # use `asyncio.Event` instead
    #     print('waiting for response ...')
    #     await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    ev = asyncio.Event()
    await ev.wait()

    return resp


async def on_btn_click_(sender, data, user_data):  # IMPORTANT this callback endswith "_"
    print('do sth step 1 ...')
    resp = await msgbox()
    if resp == 'Yes':
        print('do sth step 2 ...')
    print('done')


def on_input_change_sync(sender, data, user_data):
    dpg.set_value(user_data, data)


async def on_input_change(sender, data, user_data):
    dpg.set_value(user_data, data)


async def on_input_change_(sender, data, user_data):
    dpg.set_value(user_data, data)


async def main():
    with dpg.window(tag='prim'):
        dpg.add_button(label='Submit', callback=on_btn_click_)
        dpg.add_input_text(callback=on_input_change_sync, user_data='lable0', label='sync')
        dpg.add_text(tag='lable0')
        dpg.add_input_text(callback=on_input_change_, user_data='lable1', label='create_task')
        dpg.add_text(tag='lable1')
        dpg.add_input_text(callback=on_input_change, user_data='lable2', label='await')
        dpg.add_text(tag='lable2')
    dpg.create_viewport(title='test msgbox', width=600, height=300)

    # start_dpg()
    dpg.setup_dearpygui()
    dpg.set_primary_window('prim', True)
    dpg.show_viewport()
    dpg.configure_app(manual_callback_management=True)
    while dpg.is_dearpygui_running():
        dpg.render_dearpygui_frame()  # placed before or after handle callback? seem same result
        jobs = dpg.get_callback_queue()  # retrieves and clears queue
        await run_callbacks(jobs)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    dpg.destroy_context()


async def run_callbacks(jobs):
    if jobs is None:
        pass
    else:
        for job in jobs:
            if job[0] is None:
                continue
            sig = inspect.signature(job[0])
            args = []
            for i in range(len(sig.parameters)):
                args.append(job[i+1])
            result = job[0](*args)
            # diff. callback function naming style for diff. handle method
            if inspect.isawaitable(result):
                if result.__name__.endswith('_'):
                    print(f'creat task for: {result.__name__}')
                    # start corotine without waiting for its result - not follow register sequence
                    asyncio.create_task(result)
                else:
                    print(f'await for: {result.__name__}')
                    await result  # run callback in sequence of registered


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```